# How can add code of resend otp firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am a new application developer trying to add on my project service of otp firebase and I add it and it's work now but I don't know I can  add code of resend otp.If the user is late checking the number, he gets a resend of the code.

Before I published the question, I checked for similar topics on the site that were previously published but it did not work for me.

this is my code:

```
public class VerifyPhoneActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private String verificationId;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_verify_phone);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editTextCode);
        findViewById(R.id.tt).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

//=======here I want add it==============///////////

            }
        });

        String phonenumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("phonenumber");
        sendVerificationCode(phonenumber);

        findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String code = editText.getText().toString().trim();

                if (code.isEmpty() || code.length() < 6) {

                    editText.setError("Enter code...");
                    editText.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                verifyCode(code);
            }
        });

    }

    private void verifyCode(String code) {
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
        signInWithCredential(credential);
    }

    private void signInWithCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, ProfileActivitytt.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

                            startActivity(intent);

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void sendVerificationCode(String number) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                number,
                20,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,
                mCallBack
        );

    }

    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            mCallBack = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
            verificationId = s;
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
            if (code != null) {
                editText.setText(code);
                verifyCode(code);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            Toast.makeText(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `sendVerificationCode(String number)` again , on click of resend button